# How to use date event in week calendar

Tags: jquery

I'm looking at the documentation for the [week calendar plugin](https://github.com/robmonie/jquery-week-calendar/wiki)

And unfortunately, some of the configurations are unclear to me and I can't seem to figure out how to use the Date function. So basically, I need to know, how can you use the Date function?

I tried something like this:

```
date: {default: "now"}
date: now
default: now
```

But none of these worked.

Comment: You know that the code is 3 years old? Just asking...

Answer (score 1):

Try Like this :

```
   $('#calendar').weekCalendar({
        events:[{"id":10182,
          "start":"2009-05-03T12:15:00.000+10:00",
          "end":"2009-05-03T13:15:00.000+10:00",
          "title":"Lunch with Mike"
        }, {
          "id":10182,
          "start":"2009-05-03T14:00:00.000+10:00",
          "end":"2009-05-03T15:00:00.000+10:00",
          "title":"Dev Meeting"
        }],
options : {
    timeslotsPerHour : 3,
"date":"2012-10-30"
  },

  });
```

try changing the format of date also, 
As in docs , Calendar Events Data Structure

```
data = {
  options : {
    timeslotsPerHour : 3
  },
  events : [ ... ]
}
```